# How can i use Security Trimming in Data view webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, security-trimming

I noticed if i have a custom webpart and i'm sure the user doesn't have access to the list.The users still see the content(link title for example) but only get access denied when they click on it.
This particular scenario is when connecting via webservices using via web services.
Is it possible to hide the whole data webpart based on permissions.

Also tried using SharePointWebControls:SPSecurityTrimmedControl around the webpart but no show :(

I have also read about the target audiences but can i use this without setting up user profile?Will this work with AD groups/SP groups?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Target Audience can be used with SharePoint Groups. If you plan on using AD Groups as well, you'll need to map those groups to SharePoint Groups to fully use the Target Audience functionality.